# Different ways to evaluate area partitions

Tags: geometry, reference-request, algorithms, polygons

Given a polygon either convex or concave, suppose we generate a partition of the polygon into multiple smaller polygons. What are the existing literature sources that describe different, complex and novel ways to score one such partition? Simple ones are the average areas of smaller polygons. A complex one would be the average time taken for TSP tour of randomly sampled points in each partition. What are other involved, novel ways to score them?

Comment: Any thoughts about my answer?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes it is pretty exhaustive. I have ticked it. But i was also looking for sources that study the significance of different measures theoretically. Eg. is there a theoretical study that xyz measure will lead to better partitions, mathematical justification for which measure is better than other and why? etc. But i guess that should be a new question, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Average perimeter of smaller polygons.

Average total length of minimal length spanning tree of randomly sampled points in each partition.

Average diameter of smaller polygons.

Maximum minimum distance between randomly sampled points in each partition.

Minimum maximum distance between randomly sampled points in each partition.